# JTable (BeanTableModel) not updating/refreshing - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablemodel

I've 2 panels. One where the user inserts the data and the other with a `JTable` where the results will be shown.

My problem is when the user press's the ok (in my case apply) `JButton` the data is computed but is not shown on the `JTable`, nothing changes in the `JTable`.

For my `JTable` I'm using the `Bean Table Model` from tips4Java (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/27/bean-table-model/).

One weird thing is if I send data (lets call this data 'A') to the table when the program starts it is shown on the table and if later on I try to update the table, the table does not update. But when I don't send data to the table at start up but try to update/send the table with data 'A' it does not update.

So my question is, why is not the `JTable` showing whatever data I send to?

Here's my code:

JButton listenere that starts the processing and sends the data to the table:

```
crashForm.setFormListener(new FormListener() {
    @Override
    public void formEvent(OptionsFormEvent oe) {
        String readTable = oe.getReadFromTable();
        int access = oe.getAccess();
        int transition = oe.getTransition();
        boolean smooth = oe.isTrainCrash();
        ArrayList<String> allTrains = new ArrayList<>();
        List crashedTrainList = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            allTrains = controller.getUniqueTrains(controller.connectServer(), readTable, "trainid");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured while getting trains data\n"
                    + "Error description: " + ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < allTrains.size(); i++) 
            {
                ArrayList<Train> trainDataList = new ArrayList<>();
                ArrayList<Train> crashedProccessedData = new ArrayList<>();

                String query = "the sql query...";

                trainDataList = controller.getTrainData(controller.connectServer(), readTable, query);

                crashedProccessedData = controller.detectCrash(access, transition, trainDataList);
                crashedTrainList.addAll(crashedProccessedData);

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "An error occured while detecting a crash.\n"
                    + "Error description: " + ex.getMessage(), "Error",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        System.out.println("Total crashes detected:" + crashedTrainList.size());
        tablePanel.createTable(Train.class, crashedTrainList, true, false, tableLabels);
        tablePanel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
});
}
```

And here's my tablePanel class:

```
    public TablePanel() {
    }
    public void createTable(Class c, List data, boolean toolBarUp, 
            boolean toolBarBottom, ArrayList<String> labelsCheckBox) {

        beanTableModel = new BeanTableModel(c, data);
        columnModel = new XTableColumnModel();
        table = new JTable(beanTableModel);
        table.setColumnModel(columnModel);
        table.createDefaultColumnsFromModel();

        if(toolBarUp == true)
        {
            final JToolBar toolBarTop = new JToolBar();

            // Create the Show ALL
            JButton reset = new JButton("Reset");

            reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                for(Component c : toolBarTop.getComponents()){
                    if(c instanceof JCheckBox){
                        JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox) c;
                        checkBox.setSelected(false);
                        columnModel.setAllColumnsVisible();
                    }
                }
                int numberOfColumn = columnModel.getColumnCount();

                for(int aux = 0; aux < numberOfColumn; aux++)
                {
                    int num = columnModel.getColumnCount();
                    TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumnByModelIndex(aux);
                    columnModel.setColumnVisible(column, true);
                }
            }
            });

            toolBarTop.add(reset);

            // Create a JCheckBox for each column
            for(int i = 0; i < labelsCheckBox.size(); i++)
            {
                final int index = i;
                toolBarTop.add(new JCheckBox(new AbstractAction(labelsCheckBox.get(i)) {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        TableColumn column = columnModel.getColumnByModelIndex(index);
                        boolean visible = columnModel.isColumnVisible(column);
                        columnModel.setColumnVisible(column, !visible);
                    }
                }));
            }



            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(toolBarTop, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
//            add(toolBarDown, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }


        final JToolBar toolBarDown = new JToolBar();

        toolBarDown.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Save Table") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        }));


    }

    public void createTable(Class c, Class cAncestor) {
        beanTableModel = new BeanTableModel(c, cAncestor);
        table = new JTable(beanTableModel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void createTable(Class c, Class cAncestor, List data) {
        beanTableModel = new BeanTableModel(c, cAncestor, data);
        table = new JTable(beanTableModel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        beanTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public void createTable(Class c) {
        beanTableModel = new BeanTableModel(c);
        table = new JTable(beanTableModel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public void createTable(Class c, List data)
    {
        beanTableModel = new BeanTableModel(c, data);
        table = new JTable(beanTableModel);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    //to refresh the table everytime there is an update
    public void fireTableDataChanged()
    {
        beanTableModel.fireTableDataChanged();
    }
```

So again, my question is: Isn't my `JTable` not updated with the new results every time I send new data to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never invoke fireTableDataChanged manually. Only the TableModel is responsible for invoking this event.

From your code it looks like you are creating a new TableModel, JTable and JScrollPane every time you make a change. Any time you add a component to a visible GUI the basic code should be:

```
panel.add(....);
panel.revalidate();
panel.repaint();
```

By default all components have a size of zero so since you don't invoke revalidate() then never get a proper size and there is nothing to paint. Also, it is never a good idea to simply keep adding components to the CENTER of your panel since the old component are still part of the container.

However, there is a better solution. There is no need to keep creating new components. All you need to do is create an new TableModel and then use:

```
table.setModel( newlyCreatedModel );
```

and the model will be added to the table and the table will repaint itself automatically.